# how to create info button on uinavigationbar on iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I've seen many of applications that have an info button (the letter "i" with a circle around it) on the uinavigationbar.  How do I add this type of button?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The previous answer was close, didn't quite compile. Here's what you really want:

```
// Info button
UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight]; 
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfoView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
```

Comment: How does one go about implementing the "showInfoView" method that you pointed out?

Comment: Shawn, just have -(void)showInfoView:(id)sender { elsewhere in your implementation. If there's no : at the end of the method, no arguments will be passed in and you can do without the :(id)sender.

Answer (score 3):

There is memory leak in the answer above. You should use "autorelease" to avoid it. I have tried to edit the answer but I wasn't successful so far.

```
// Info button
UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight]; 
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfoView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton] autorelease];
```

THIS IS THE CORRECT WAY TO DO IT.

Comment: The correct action would not be to edit the answer but to post your own answer *with your version of the solution* or, once you get to 50 reputation, to comment on the answer so the poster can correct it. Comments with no solution that are posted as answers are likely to be deleted. Finally, there is no "answer above" because position of the answers depends on the sort tab used to view the page, votes and whether an answer is accepted or deleted. Better to refer to answers or comments on the page by poster's name.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an "Info Light" type button to the navigationItem of the view controller that the UINavigationController is currently displaying.  Something like this could go in your view controller code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  UIButton * info = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
  // set your button's target and selector for whatever action here.
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView = info;
}
```

Comment: Kevlar, Please modify your answer.. buttonType is a readonly property. You can't set it!

Comment: my bad, i was going from memory and didnt have the docs in front of me; changing now.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use your current bar button item's target and selector for your info button.

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[infoButton addTarget:self.barButtonItem.target action:self.barButtonItem.action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.barButtonItem.customView = infoButton;
```

This way, any actions or segues coupled to your bar button item will be transferred to your info button.